# I need a script to generate time in sending form

Tags: javascript, html, date

I need a code so I can place a date on this infusion form so I can track the day they submit it.. I think there is an onClick code I found but it did not work.

```
<form class="infusion-form" action="https://xxxx.infusionsoft.com" method="post">
    <input name="DATE" type="hidden" value="">
   <p>*First Name:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_FirstName" class="default-input" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
   <p>*Last Name:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_LastName" class="default-input" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" />
   <p>*Email Address:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_Email" class="default-input" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
   <p>*Primary Phone No:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_Phone1" class="default-input" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text" />
   <p>*Address:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_Address2Street1" class="default-input" name="inf_field_Address2Street1" type="text" />
   <p>*City:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_City2" class="default-input" name="inf_field_City2" type="text" />
   <p>*State:</p>
        <input id="inf_field_State2" class="default-input" name="inf_field_State2" type="text" />

    <input id="Submit" class="btn button inf-button" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you need JS to do that. I can send whatever time I want. You should do that on the server.

Comment: @iSZ—it would be better to use `new Date().toISOString()`, since the output of *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent and may not be easily parsable by the server.

Comment: @RobG Thanks I think that is a better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to achieve what you've asked for. The date format is edited to `toISOString` as suggested by Bakudan in the comments above.

Also mentioned in the comments it is better to set the time of the submission on the server, this way you can make sure the time on the computer is current and avoid a user falsifying the time.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var dateStr = new Date().toISOString();
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('submissionDate');
  dateInput.value=dateStr;
}
```

```html
<input id="submissionDate" type="hidden" name="submissionDate" value="">
```